# How to find the index of a missing element?

Tags: python, list

Let's say you have the following lists:

```
fruit_types = ["apple","pear","strawberry","mango"]
fruits = ["apple","strawberry","mango"]
```

How would I write a loop that identifies that the "pear" element is missing in the 
"fruits" list's 2nd index?

I do know the first step begins with:

```
for element in fruit_types:
    if element not in fruits:
```

But I am completely lost where else to go from here.

Comment: I think you are going to need to specify this a little bit more

Comment: Hint: What do you do if the `if` condition is true? Remember back to class when your professor was explaining the assignment to you

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If the "if" condition is true, the loop should identify the index where the missing element should be.

Comment: Okay. Good. Next hint. Look at `enumerate`.

Answer (score 3):

The above set differences work. But in case you wanted code that only checks if one of the two lists has missing elements (In your style). You could use the enumerate function.

```
fruit_types = ["apple","pear","strawberry","mango"]
fruits = ["apple","strawberry","mango"]

def find_missing_index():
    for index, element in enumerate(fruit_types):
        if element not in fruits:
            print(fruit_types[index], index)

def main():
    find_missing_index()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

No doubt you wanted the set difference code however which there are plenty of examples from others.

---

For added performance, it would be wise to convert `fruits` to a `set` in advance.

```
fset = set(fruits)
for index, element in enumerate(fruit_types):
    if element not in fset:
        print(fruit_types[index], index)
```

This reduces the membership test to constant, `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: Why? `if elements not in fruits` is more inefficient than a `set difference` followed by an `index` search.

Comment: Thanks for that coldspeed. :) Thought it would be better to show the simple insertion of the enumerate function in his own code (for better understanding). But that's even better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use difference operation on `set` to find this.

```
fruit_types = ["apple","pear","strawberry","mango"]
fruits = ["apple","strawberry","mango"]

missings = list(set(fruits_types) - set(fruit))
print missings
```

If this is cool, then why use loops?

Then to get index of the missing item:

```
for missing in missings:
    print fruit_types.index(missing)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is not the best answer. When you could've easily done this in linear time, do you need to keep calling `index` in a loop?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Sorry? This prints it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I am not aware of that. Can you please leave it as comment or edit my answer so that we can learn something new? :) Thanks

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ does index take *list* also?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Also, I only meant to leave feedback about your current solution, nothing more.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The iteration for index is fine. Do you have any suggestions here?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Yes

Answer (score 0):

Using sets difference, and finding the index:

```
fruit_types = ["apple","pear","strawberry","mango"]
fruits = ["apple","strawberry","mango"]

missings = set(fruit_types) - set(fruits)
for missing in missings:
    print(fruit_types.index(missing))
```

#### output:

```
1  # which is the index of the missing element in fruit_types
```

Comment: Same as above, you really shouldn't be calling `.index` in a loop. This becomes quadratic in the worst case.

Comment: Quadratic for lists of 4 elements is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: For 4 elements, maybe, but you wouldn't want to propagate that mindset forward, would you?

Comment: Which are you referring to as "overkill complicated code that is bug prone?"

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
fruit_types = ["apple","pear","strawberry","mango"]
fruits = ["apple","strawberry","mango"]
missing_elements = []
for element in fruit_types:
    if(element not in fruits):
        missing_elements.append(element)
print(missing_elements)
>>> ["pear"]
```

Create an empty list, then add to that list if the element is not in fruits.